# Is it mandatory to use MQ to make microservices communicate with each other?

Tags: architecture, microservices, message-queue

I'm developing an application on microservice architecture.  I'm stuck with the idea of proper integration of MQ.

Do we need to add mq to any communication between microservices?  I'm using feign server to make communication between services and kafka to make communication between several services, because they need async communication.

If yes, why should we do this? If not why shouldn't we do this?

Comment: There's never a need to use a specific tool for something. You can always use anything else that fits for your purpose. If tools are recommended for something, it's always because others have found it useful, but that doesn't mean it fits your particular purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, basically you mean that using mq is not mandatory for every microservice? Only if we need asyns?

Comment: What I'm saying is that this is up to you. It may be helpful, but not using it might be simpler in some cases. When you use a tool, you always need to ask yourself: Is this the right tool _for what I'm doing now_. And if it complicates things, the answer may be "no".

Comment: gRPC is also async, and doesn't need a queue. The queue prevents point to point service socket connections, but the same could be achieved with a transactional database or distributed filesystem rather than a queue... Also, feign is for http, last I checked, not Kafka client